# base64ToBinary(body('Parse_JSON__-_Current_item')?['imageData']?['data']?['$binary']?['base64'])' cannot be evaluated

Tags: development, power-automate, ms-flow

I have the following action:-

[image]

but on run-time , i am getting this error on some items:-

> Unable to process template language expressions in action
> 'Compose_-*Convert_Base64ToBinary_2' inputs at line '1' and column
> '6760': 'The template language expression
> 'base64ToBinary(body('Parse_JSON*_-_Current_item')?['imageData']?['data']?['$binary']?['base64'])'
> cannot be evaluated because property 'base64' cannot be selected.
> Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.

[image]

any advice please?

Here is the Parse_JSON_current_item data for the item which is raising the above error.. i added **** on the binary data as the real data is very huge:-

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5bb4f2b22ec14974eeed4899"
  },
  "normalized_otherCategory": "",
  "category": "electronics",
  "location": "ontrain",
  "referenceNumber": "VIAF-000000085",
  "archivingDate": {
    "$date": "2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb4f2b22ec14974eeed4896"
      },
      "type": "created",
      "user": "RO454001",
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2018-10-03T16:47:46.983Z"
      },
      "normalized_comment": [],
      "configs": []
    },
    {
      "type": "comment",
      "comment": "On 90 day shelf ",
      "user": "RO454001",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb4f2b22ec14974eeed4895"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2018-10-03T16:47:46.983Z"
      },
      "normalized_comment": [
        "on",
        "90",
        "day",
        "shelf"
      ],
      "configs": []
    },
    {
      "type": "stored",
      "user": "RO454001",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb4f2b22ec14974eeed4894"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2018-10-03T16:47:46.983Z"
      },
      "normalized_comment": [],
      "configs": [
        "container-2",
        "station-toronto"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "otherAttributes": [
    {
      "type": "type",
      "value": "Laptop Charger",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb4f2b22ec14974eeed4898"
      },
      "normalized_value": [
        "laptop",
        "charger"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "brand",
      "value": "HP",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb4f2b22ec14974eeed4897"
      },
      "normalized_value": [
        "hp"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    "other",
    "other",
    "color-black"
  ],
  "timestamp": {
   "$date": "2018-10-03T16:47:46.982Z"
  },
  "foundDate": {
    "$date": "2018-08-12T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "trainFoundAt": {
    "number": "79",
    "car": "0",
    "seat": ""
  },
  "status": "opened",
  "matchIdNumber": "",
  "__v": 0,
  "imageData": {
    "originalName": "image.jpg_big.jpg",
    "contentType": "images/jpeg",
    "data": {
      "$binary": "/9j//E********//Z",
      "$type": "00"
    }
  },
  "imageThumbData": {
    "originalName": "image.jpg_thumb.jpg",
    "contentType": "images/jpeg",
    "data": {
      "$binary": "/9j/*******/9k=",
      "$type": "00"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using this: `base64ToBinary(body('Parse_JSON__-_Current_item')?['imageData']?['data']?['$binary'])`. let me know if it works.

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes seems it is working... so can i know why my formula did not work?

Comment: You were trying to read `base64` property inside `$binary` (considering it is an object). But `$binary` is a string containing base64 value (which is what you needed). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below formula, it should work for you:

```
base64ToBinary(body('Parse_JSON__-_Current_item')?['imageData']?['data']?['$binary'])
```